# Finding the three unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Can someone show me the steps to finding the three unknowns of these two equations.

$$-a-bx+cx^2 = x^2+2x+1$$

The answers are $a=\ ...\ $, $b=\ ...\ $, and $c=\ ...$ , but I can't see how they worked this out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can try putting some values of $x$, for example try $x=0$ and see what happens..

Comment: That is only 1 equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-a-bx+cx^2 = x^2+2x+1$

put $x=0$ to get $a=-1$

Now put $x=1$ to get $c-b=3$ and put $x=-1$ to get $c+b=-1$ Solving we get $b=-2,c=1$

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$
\color{blue}1x^2+\color{red}2x+\color{green}1=\color{blue}cx^2\color{red}{-b}x\color{green}{-a}.
$$
By comparing LHS and RHS, we will immediately notice that $c=1$, $-b=2$, and $-a=1$.

Comment: It's important to notice here that the solutions for $a,b,c$ are unique due to the linear independence of $\{1,x,x^2\}$ on $\mathbb{P}_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have two quadratic curves. It is a fact that, just as two points determine a line, three points determine a quadratic. So if these two go through the same set of points, as is implied by the fact that they are equal, they must in fact be the *same quadratic*; that is, the coefficients of $x^2$, $x$, and the constant must match. Thus $g=1$, $b=-2$, and $a=-1$.

As pointed out in a comment, you can also figure this out by substituting three different values for $x$, giving three linear equations in the three unknowns $a$, $b$, and $g$, and solve the equations.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$ are two polynomials, then $Q(x)=P(x)$ if and only if the coefficient of each $y$ degree term in $Q(x)$, is equal to the coefficient of the corresponding $y$ degree term in $P(x)$.

This means that if $ax+b=cx+d$ then $a=c$ and $b=d.$ Can you use this property in your example to determine the values of the unknowns?